# A função password_hash do PHP é um wrapper para a função crypt?

Tags: php, funções, segurança, característica-linguagem, password

A função `password_hash` me parece um wrapper que adiciona uma camada de alto nível na função `crypt`, pois ela traz uma configuração padrão que poderia ser feita com `crypt` manualmente.

Acontece o mesmo com a função `password_verify`, que parece equivalente a isso:

```
function password_verify($password, $passwordHash)
{
     return (crypt($password, $passwordHash) === $passwordHash);
}
```

Tenho essa curiosidade em saber se são wrappers adicionados para `crypt` nas versão mais recentes do PHP.

**OBS:** Sei que o código acima é inseguro, pois está vulnerável a timming attack, porém é só uma forma de tentar ilustrar a ideia. O ponto é saber se é um wrapper ou não. Portanto, segurança não é o foco desta pergunta.

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse código é inseguro, por usar `===`.

O `password_hash` também suporta o Argon2, nas últimas versões do PHP, coisa que não é suportada pelo crypt. O crypt também varia de plataforma para plataforma, e nem todos os algoritmos podem estar disponível, inclusive pode nao existir o BCrypt.

A função crypt também exige um salt, que deve ser único. No password_hash isso é gerado internamente na função.

Entretanto, sim, ele é um wrapper. Isso é mencionado na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php):

> "password_hash() is a simple crypt() wrapper and compatible with existing password hashes"